# Parsing a binary Redis key

Tags: c#, string, redis

I wrote a **16-byte** binary key to Redis. When I query the key, it comes back in the following format:

```
\xc9;\xfd5\x80\x00\xa9Z\xc9\x0fb\xef\x7f\xd6V]
```

What format is this `string`? It looks like it ought to be hex (`\x`) but there are other characters in there that aren't valid hex characters.

How do I *convert* this `string` back into my original byte array `byte[]` (using C#)?

Comment: How are you querying for the key? The KEYS command? It seems very odd that you would get it back in a different format. It might be helpful to post the code that sets and queries the key

Comment: Is the initial array `[c9, 3b, fd, 35, 80, 00, a9, 5a, c9, 0f, 62, ef, 7f, d6, 56, 5d]` (in decimal: `[201, 59, 253, 53, 128, 0, 169, 90, 201, 15, 98, 239, 127, 214, 86, 93]`)?

Comment: @ste-fu - yes, it was written with StackExchange.Redis as a `byte[]` and read back using the KEYS command hence why it came back in a different (printable) format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you write a byte array `byte[]` but read it as a `string`. Some codes like `0x35` correspond to valid ASCII characters (`'5'`), some codes like  `0x00` are not and thus represented as `\x00` and so you have a strange looking string.

Let's try to parse the composed string back to original `byte[]`.

First, let's get rid of `\x..` format and have a *valid string* with a help of regular expressions:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = @"\xc9;\xfd5\x80\x00\xa9Z\xc9\x0fb\xef\x7f\xd6V]";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
    source,
   @"\\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}",
    m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Value.Substring(2), 16)).ToString());
```

Second, let's get `byte[]` from the string, assuming that all characters are ASCII:

```
  byte[] array = result
    .Select(c => (byte)c)
    .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look at the `array`:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", array.Select(x => $"{x:x2}")));
```

Outcome:

```
  c9, 3b, fd, 35, 80, 00, a9, 5a, c9, 0f, 62, ef, 7f, d6, 56, 5d
```